# recaptcha not showing in ie7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, recaptcha

I'm not getting recaptcha to show in IE 7 .  I've looked into several things on the page and nothing seems to make a difference.   Following is page is the one with the issues, if anybody wants to check it out that would be awesome.

http://www.nolimitwheels.com/testRedirect.php

Comment: works for me on ie9 (running in ie7 mode) .

Comment: @amal - IE7-compatibility mode is known to have significant differences from a real IE7. I don't know if it's the difference in this case, but in general I wouldn't recommend relying on compatibility mode for anything.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the headers because with the w3 some of the code doesn't pass the revision.

You should try these headers:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Comment: To add source code that may contain a `<` you have to indent it by four spaces or one tab. The `{}` button in the editor does that for you (selecting text → clicking `{}` → code is indented correctly).